# Performing data error correction on Byte level, to video stream

Tags: c++, c

Does anyone has an idea for efficient error correction algorithm?
Suppose all the operations and manipulation on the stream is on
the Byte level.

Comment: Error correction? What kind of error? For transmissions of any kind, Reed-Solomon is common, for example... But red eye reduction/removal is a different type of “error correction”.

Comment: Flip bits kind of error lets say 10^-6 chance

Comment: Reed-Solomon would be a good choice then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Reed-Solomon error correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed-Solomon_error_correction)?

Comment: Well I thought so , I'm not sure its the best approach

Comment: Why not? It's a very popular method, and you should find plenty of implementations of it, especially in C++. That alone should be a bonus, since you won't have to debug that code. But if you're not sure if it's the best for you - check out the Wikipedia article link. It has a thorough description of the method, as well as several links to other competing and complementing algorithms.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what are requirements. Have a look at [Raptor wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raptor_code). RFC is [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6330).
Qualcomm has nice video demonstration that might be of interest to you.